# Login page does not display in browser following 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, html, spring, redirect, http-headers

## Scenario

I have a web app using Spring Security implementing a basic custom login redirect.  My web app is running on a Tomcat 8.0.14 back-end, while my custom signin.html and .css files are served from an Apache front-end.

My call flow is like this:

1. Send a GET request to sit.html
2. site.html executes an ajax GET request for a restricted resource in my web-app
3. My web-app responds with 302 including a redirect to my custom signin.html page.
4. The client sends a GET request to access the redirect URL.
5. server responds with status 200 ok, **but the login page is not displayed in the web browser**.  In chrome debugger, I can see the response includes the signin.html page.

I can see the login page when i enter the URL directly into the browser.

The requeste header from step 4 of the call flow contains

> `Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`

whilethe request headers from accessing the login page directly contains

> `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

So it would appear the chrome browser isn't displaying the login.html because the request headers don't accept html and xml data.

## Question

If that's the case, my question is how do I control the value of the Accept header after receiving a redirect response from my web-app?  Is that something that needs to be done in the redirect response from step 3?

Here is my redirect response headers:

> `HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   Date: Sun, 19 Jul 2015 00:49:37 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) mod_jk/1.2.40
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Expires: 0
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=...; Path=...; HttpOnly
>   Location: http://.../signin.html
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
>   Connection: Keep-Alive`

Comment: This might be of some help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Comment: Explicitly set Accept header to "application/json,text/javascript,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml" in my ajax request method.  This is called during the GET request in step 2.  The Accept value is retained in step 4 request, but the return html page is still not being displayed in the browser.